# Calculate a field with date from previous rows

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table like the one shown in the image below. In this table, I need to calculate two new fields(The Red and Yellow fields), but this fields depends on the previous values. I have to calculate this values in BigQuery/SQL. In Excel, it is very easy, but I don't know how to do it in SQL.

I've tried doing a join with the same table, but previous week, and it works, but for only one "Future Week". (And there are about 100 Future Weeks)

How can I calculate this in BigQuery?
I was thinking in a Cursor.. but as far as I know, there are no cursors in BigQuery

Thanks

This is the example data:

```
WITH Data as ( Select '2021-01-03' as Week, 1000 as InboundReal, 10000 as StockReal, 1190 as SellReal, 1200 as InboundPpto UNION ALL
Select '2021-01-31',1000, 10000 , 1190 , 1200 UNION ALL Select '2021-02-07',1000, 10000 , 1190 , 1200 UNION ALL
Select '2021-02-14',1000, 10000 , 1200 , 1200 UNION ALL Select '2021-02-21',NULL,NULL,NULL,1200 UNION ALL
Select '2021-02-28',NULL,NULL,NULL,1200 UNION ALL Select '2021-03-07',NULL,NULL,NULL,1200 UNION ALL Select '2021-03-14',NULL,NULL,NULL,1200 )
Select *, NULL as ForecastSell,NULL as StockForecast FROM Data
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this type of problem comes really into the SQL domain.

It is more of an iterative problem, where state of each iteration is maintained and available for the next one immediately (which is not the case in SQL). You can run multiple SQL queries in serial to easily achieve this though. Also, explore [scripting](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting) options in BigQuery.

Comment: I was thinking maybe using a Windows Function.. like this: https://datarunsdeep.com.au/blog/cool-things-you-can-do-using-window-functions-bigquery but still cant figure it out how.. The rolling average seems similar